# How to maintain UIBlurEffect throughout swipe in PageViewController?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uiblureffect

I implemented a `UIBlurEffect` on on my VC presented by a `PageViewController` however, when you swipe the VC to the left as the new VC comes on the screen from the right (with a blur effect), the departing VC looses it's blur effect.  Is there a way I can maintain the effect until it's completely gone? (below is my SinglePageViewController's relevant code)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url  = NSURL(string: imageURL!), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) { //TODO: unwrap optional
            image.image = UIImage(data: data)

        }

        backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: backgroundImageName!))
        backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, atIndex: 0)

        // 1
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
        // 2
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        // 3
        blurView.frame = backgroundImage.bounds
        blurView.alpha = 0.9

        self.view.insertSubview(blurView, atIndex: 1)
}
```

Comment: Could you show some relevant code for how you use the `BlurEffect`?

Comment: @YuchenZhong added thanks